# QVector comparison operator overloading compiling error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am having a few issues trying to overwrite the following `==` operator.
Here is my code:

```
class ProcedureList
{
public:
    ProcedureList();
    ~ProcedureList();

    QVector<Procedure> getProcedures();

    bool operator==(const ProcedureList& rhs) { return this->_procedures == rhs._procedures; }
    bool operator!=(const ProcedureList& rhs) { return !operator==(rhs); }

//private:
    QVector<Procedure> _procedures;
};
```

Procedure is a simple class containint 4 QString:

```
class Procedure
{
public:
    Procedure();
    Procedure(QString name, QString version, QString binaryName, QString binaryPath);
    Procedure(const Procedure& map);
    ~Procedure();

    inline bool operator==(const Procedure& rhs) { return ((this->_name == rhs._name)&&
                                                           (this->_version == rhs._version)); }
    inline bool operator!=(const Procedure& rhs) { return !operator==(rhs); }

private:
    QString _name;
    QString _version;
    QString _binaryName;
    QString _binaryPath;
};
```

This gives me the following 2 problems:

1. If i keep `_procedures` public and I access this directly via `rhs._procedures;` I get the following linking error:

   ```
   error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found (compiling source file ***\x64-Debug\src\moc_rep_LauncherPanelInterface_source.cpp) 
   C:\***\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xutility(2789): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::equal_to<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const' (compiling source file *******\src\moc_rep_LauncherPanelInterface_source.cpp) 
   C:\***\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xutility(2789): error C2672: 'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found (compiling source file *****\main.cpp) 
   C:\***\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\xutility(2789): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::equal_to<void>::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) const' (compiling source file *****\main.cpp)
   ```
2. Furthermore I would like to keep _procedures private and it does not accept letting me set `{ return this->_procedures == rhs._getProcedures(); }` by saying:

cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const ProcedureList' to 'ProcedureList &'

Comment: Missing `const` -> `bool operator==(const ProcedureList& rhs) const`.

Comment: It seems you have `const` qualified objects (I'm guessing, since you haven't shown us a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). You can only call `const` qualified functions on constant objects.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Thanks... actually adding `const` worked!!! You guys rock! i was loosing my mind on it for a while....

Comment: @Stefano See [here](http://rextester.com/FKD3395)